# What would I do to add a Katana/Owin selfhosted WebApi as a service on a Azure Webrole

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have created a Selfhosted Owin WebApi.

Anyone have some sample or pointers on what steps I would need to go over to add it as a startup task for a webrole and have it run on the Webrole virtual machines.

The goal is at the end to be able to add it to a Azure Package in the same way one add the Remote Access moduels ect.

I am just not sure how I take the selfhosted WebApi and make it run and keep running as long as the Virtual Machine is online.

Cloud it be added as a service? and teh startup task installs it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to run it normally on IIS?

Comment: easy is not always best

Comment: If you're not going to use IIS, then you might as well use an Azure WorkerRole instead of a WebRole.

Comment: just to clarify - is your goal to reuse the webrole machine and selfhost this webapi service as well? Is there any specific reason for it to be selfhost? The appBuilder.UseWebApi() extensions can work on IIS too.

Comment: Brian, yes the question is not about web or worker role. Its about creating a module to attach to a cloud service. Yes i can use IIS with the appBuilder, but is that not the idea of Owin. Get the deployment working and I can change a few settings and it will use IIS on a webrole, or self host in a worker role. The goal here is to  deploy a WebAPI not being dependant on IIS or Web/worker role.

Comment: Maybe it turns out in the coming months that someone create a better host than IIS and I can just swap that in instead.

Comment: Your goal and your question are clearly at odds with each other. You specifically asked how to use self-hosted OWIN WebAPI on an Azure Web Role. The answer is: don't. On an Azure Web Role, use OWIN over IIS. On a Worker Role, use self-hosted. IIS is the whole point of Azure Web Roles.

Comment: Then lets say from a RoleEntryPoint, A Webrole dont need to use IIS. The only difference from a Web Role and Worker Role is that the Webrole sets up IIS for you. Nothing prevents you to run something outside IIS. I want to create a Host Independent solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have fundamentally missed the point of OWIN, which is to separate the detail of the hosting from the detail of the application or framework. You don't write a "self-hosted OWIN application"; you just write an OWIN application and decide how to host it later. If you have an OWIN-compliant application, you can run it self-hosted or on IIS just by referencing different hosting packages.

So on an Azure Web Role you would use [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb) to host the application on IIS, possibly as an additional web site within the role. In other contexts, you could use [Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener) to self-host the application in a Worker Role, a Windows Service or a desktop or console application.

Comment: I think i formulated my question bad also, but i get your point.  I have owin compliant application - and want to deploy it as a service on a virtual machine (either web or worker role), and the deployment should be as a startup task added to the cloud service. This way I can attach it to any webrole or worker role and it can provide the webapi for any of them.

Comment: Oh, I see (finally, sorry). The first thing I would try is packaging the application as a Windows Service with the OWIN self-host component, then installing and starting that service as a startup task.

Comment: The reason why I was so anti IIS was because I didnt want to depend on it. At some point I want to try use https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin as replacement and proof of concept.

Comment: Indeed, I've been meaning to take a look at Nowin too.